MudBlazor Snackbar
For some reason, the MudBlazor Snackbar on my local environment is not popping up. This is the code I have.
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

        @switch (errorCode)
    {
        case 99995:
            Snackbar.Add($"Email id {model.Email} is already used for another student. Please use a different email id for each student.", Severity.Error);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

My Program.cs has the below configuration
builder.Services.AddMudServices(config => {
config.SnackbarConfiguration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.BottomCenter; });

What else am i missing?
When my code runs, I dont see anything appear on the screen when that condition occurs. I have validated that the errorCode is 99995.

Need to provide more code in order to reproduce your issue.

Probably<MudSnackbarProvider /> in MainLayout as you haven't mentioned it in your question.
https://www.mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#manual-install-add-components

I do have that in MainLayout as well.

Does the demo https://www.mudblazor.com/components/snackbar#usage work?

It worked for me, when i added:
<Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer"/>

into the body element
and edited the Headoutlet as follows:
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer"/>

at App.razor File
This statement needs to be deleted inside of the Index.razor
@rendermode InteractiveServer


OP taged wasm so it should be <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />
